# Confusing Caching Behaviour of a Simple C Program

Tags: c, performance, caching, memory, perf

I am experimenting with a program to see if its caching behaviour is consistent with my conceptual understanding.

To do this I am using the **Perf** command:

```
perf stat -e cache-misses ./a.out
```

to record the cache-miss ratio of the following simple **C** program:

```c
int main() {
    int N = 10000;
    double *arr = malloc(sizeof(double) * N * N);

    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < N; j++){
            arr[i * N + j] = 10.0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I get a cache-miss ratio of 50.212%. If I change the array access pattern as follows:

```c
arr[j * N + i]
```

I get that the cache-miss ratio is 22.206%.

These results are surprising to me.

1. The cache-miss ratio of 50.212% seems very high for such a simple program with a very regular memory access pattern. I would expect this to be closer to 1/(num-words-per-cache-line) which is definitely larger than 1/2. Why is the cache-miss ratio so high?
2. My (limited) understanding of memory suggests that iterating over the array in column-major order should result in much worse caching behaviour but the results I am getting indicate the opposite. What's going on?

Comment: What CPU do you have? `cat /proc/cpuinfo` will tell you the cache information too.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart it is an Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU and the cache size is 12288 KB.

Comment: Did you generate the program with optimizations enabled?

Comment: Out of curiousity, does `double (*arr)[N] = malloc( sizeof(double[N][N]) );` ... `arr[i][j] = 10.0` generate faster code?

Comment: Please show the assembly generated for the two sources (GCC’s `-S` switch) and all the compiler switches you used. (Optimization must not have been enabled, because this program is equivalent to `int main() {}`.) Does `perf` start counting from the start of `main`, or does it include initialization in the C run-time start-up code? Does it include instruction cache misses?

Comment: @Lundin I am compiling the code with -03 optimisation enabled. If I recompile with -01 optimisation enabled the cache-miss ratio increases to 77.7%. Also changing the code as you describe doesn't change my results.

Comment: @EricPostpischil The compilation flags I am using are (-std=gnu99 -Wall -O3 -lm). The assembly for the row major indexing is here: http://www.writeurl.com/publish/5ipuhi3sg2iyvwkfnkht. The assembly for the column major indexing is here: http://www.writeurl.com/publish/e7qpbfees4kmm2kkmo8y. Although it is not intelligible to me.  I doubt that it includes instruction cache-misses because the miss-ratio is so high and the program has no complex control structure that would make caching instructions difficult.

Comment: In the question, you distinguish the versions based on the indexing of `i * N + j` versus `j * N + i`. In the comment above, you use “raw major” versus “column major.” In your mind, which is which? I would like to ensure I match the assembly code with the right C code. That said, the two assembly files are identical except for a swap of the indices in the address calculation. So there is no compiler optimization in one and not the other. Alternate explanations include a mix-up in matching sources with `perf` results, a bug in `perf`, or misreading the `perf` results.

Comment: Additionally, I am surprised GCC produces this assembly. Apple LLVM with `-O3` optimizes the program to simply setting up the stack frame, putting zero in the return register, and returning. GCC should have done the same.

Comment: Please include all required information in the question, not just comments. Including full compilation flags, compiler version, specific CPU model (there are many generations of intel Xeon processors), as well as the actual output of perf, not just the ratio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is pretty simple: compiler optimize out your assignments. Here is how the disassembly looks like for your code:

```
10  int main() {
   0x00000000004004d6 <+0>: mov    $0x2710,%edx
   0x00000000004004db <+5>: jmp    0x4004e7 <main+17>

15          for(int j = 0; j < N; j++){
   0x00000000004004dd <+7>: sub    $0x1,%eax
   0x00000000004004e0 <+10>:    jne    0x4004dd <main+7>

14      for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
   0x00000000004004e2 <+12>:    sub    $0x1,%edx
   0x00000000004004e5 <+15>:    je     0x4004ee <main+24>

10  int main() {
   0x00000000004004e7 <+17>:    mov    $0x2710,%eax
   0x00000000004004ec <+22>:    jmp    0x4004dd <main+7>

16              arr[i * N + j] = 10.0;
17          }
18      }
19      return 0;
20  }
   0x00000000004004ee <+24>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x00000000004004f3 <+29>:    retq
```

As you can see there are no assembler instructions generated for the line `arr[i * N + j] = 10.0;`, so those cache misses you observe with perf are unrelated.

The fix is quite easy. Simply add `volatile` to the pointer declaration, forcing compiler to generate the assignments, i.e.:

```
volatile double *arr = malloc(sizeof(double) * N * N);
```

The disassembly now:

```
10  int main() {
   0x0000000000400526 <+0>: sub    $0x8,%rsp

11      int N = 10000;
12      volatile double *arr = malloc(sizeof(double) * N * N);
   0x000000000040052a <+4>: mov    $0x2faf0800,%edi
   0x000000000040052f <+9>: callq  0x400410 <malloc@plt>
   0x0000000000400534 <+14>:    mov    $0x0,%edx

16              arr[i * N + j] = 10.0;
   0x0000000000400539 <+19>:    movsd  0xc7(%rip),%xmm0        # 0x400608
   0x0000000000400541 <+27>:    jmp    0x40055f <main+57>
   0x0000000000400543 <+29>:    movslq %edx,%rcx
   0x0000000000400546 <+32>:    lea    (%rax,%rcx,8),%rcx
   0x000000000040054a <+36>:    movsd  %xmm0,(%rcx)
   0x000000000040054e <+40>:    add    $0x1,%edx

15          for(int j = 0; j < N; j++){
   0x0000000000400551 <+43>:    cmp    %esi,%edx
   0x0000000000400553 <+45>:    jne    0x400543 <main+29>
   0x0000000000400555 <+47>:    mov    %esi,%edx

14      for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
   0x0000000000400557 <+49>:    cmp    $0x5f5e100,%esi
   0x000000000040055d <+55>:    je     0x400567 <main+65>
   0x000000000040055f <+57>:    lea    0x2710(%rdx),%esi
   0x0000000000400565 <+63>:    jmp    0x400543 <main+29>

17          }
18      }
19      return 0;
20  }
   0x0000000000400567 <+65>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x000000000040056c <+70>:    add    $0x8,%rsp
   0x0000000000400570 <+74>:    retq
```

And there are much more cache misses as well.

Running your test just once might get you very noisy results. You should run your measurements few times and take a median. There are benchmark frameworks, like Google Benchmark, so please have a look.

And the last one. Both of your patterns, like `i * N + j` and `j * N + i` are easily recognizable by the CPU prefetcher, so the cache miss ratio in both cases should be quite similar...